# Do custom iterators always need to explicitly specify value_type?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20

Since [iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) is deprecated, I began converting iterators in my code base to use non-deprecated constructs.  I could not seem to make my indirect iterator compliant with the `std::forward_iterator` concept unless I explicitly specified `value_type`.  I would like to know if this is expected.

Based on the definition of [iter_value_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t) and [indirectly_readible_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirectly_readable_traits), it seems like there is no automatic inference of `std::iter_value_t`.  Naively, I would have expected `std::iter_value_t<Itr>` to be defined as `std::remove_cvref_t<std::iter_reference_t<Itr>>` if no definition for `value_type` is present (which is checked via `has-member-value-type` in [indirectly_readible_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirectly_readable_traits)).

```
#include <vector>

template <std::forward_iterator Itr>
class IndirectItr {
public:
    using value_type = std::iter_value_t<Itr>; // **do I need this?**
    
    explicit IndirectItr(Itr itr = {}) : m_itr{itr} {}
    bool operator==(const IndirectItr& rhs) const { return m_itr == rhs.m_itr; }
    bool operator!=(const IndirectItr& rhs) const { return m_itr != rhs.m_itr; }
    typename std::iter_reference_t<Itr> operator *() const { return *m_itr; }
    IndirectItr& operator++() { ++m_itr; return *this; }
    IndirectItr operator++(int) { auto ret = *this; ++(*this); return ret; }
    typename std::iter_difference_t<Itr> operator-(const IndirectItr& rhs) const { return m_itr - rhs.m_itr; }

private:
    Itr m_itr;
};

using Base = std::vector<int>::iterator;
static_assert(std::forward_iterator<IndirectItr<Base>>);
static_assert(std::same_as<std::iter_value_t<Base>, std::remove_cvref_t<std::iter_reference_t<Base>>>);
```

P.S. I have several indirect iterator definitions that wrap other iterators.  The example above is representative of a custom indirect iterator.  I don't have this exact class in my code.

Answer (score 1):

`std::forward_iterator` includes `std::input_iterator`, which includes [`std::indirectly_readable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirectly_readable), which contains:

```
requires(const In in) {
  typename std::iter_value_t<In>;
  typename std::iter_reference_t<In>;
  typename std::iter_rvalue_reference_t<In>;
  { *in } -> std::same_as<std::iter_reference_t<In>>;
  { ranges::iter_move(in) } -> std::same_as<std::iter_rvalue_reference_t<In>>;
}
```

(where `In` is `std::remove_cvref_t<IndirectItr<Base>>`).

That `typename std::iter_value_t<In>;` line requires you to declare a `value_type` or to specialize `std::iterator_traits<IndirectItr<Base>>` (and provide `value_type` there), as explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t).

You cannot specialize `std::iterator_traits<IndirectItr<T>>` for all `T` ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927764/specializing-iterator-traits)), so you can either pick the first and very reasonable option, or fully specialize for each `IndirectItr` you intend to use.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have a member `value_type` on your iterator. But your only alternative is to specialize `iterator_traits<T>` for your iterator type and provide a `value_type` alias there. So you may as well make it a member of the iterator.

The `value_type` cannot be computed from something else, as it may have no obvious relation to `reference` or any other operation on the iterator. This is one of the things that allows for proxy iterators, which pre-C++20 concepts did not.