# C++ template function taking template class as parameter

Tags: c++, templates, parameters

I'm struggling with the following code. Basically, I have a class Foo and nested class Bar, and now I want to pass a pointer of class Bar object to a function, but it doesn't compile. Could anyone help me with this? Thank you.

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar
    {
        T data_;
    };
    Bar bar_;
};

template <typename T>
void func(Foo<T>::Bar* bar) // Why is this line wrong???
{
}

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo.bar_.data_ = 17;
    func(&foo.bar_);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++, template argument can not be deduced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060824/c-template-argument-can-not-be-deduced)

Comment: (at least, a duplicate once solve the obvious `typename` issue, which VC++ would probably let slip as usual anyway)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to have the following signature

```
template <typename T>
void func(typename Foo<T>::Bar* bar) // Why is this line wrong???
```

However, that is not the only problem

```
func(&foo.bar_);
```

also needs to be

```
func<int>(&foo.bar_);
```

This is because you are calling the templated function "func" but its type can not be deduced. Without its type, it will give an error such as

```
no matching function for call to 'func(Foo<int>::Bar*)'
```

Comment: +1. Correct answer. The bigger problem is : `T` cannot be deduced, so it needs to be passed explicitly.

Comment: +1 I like newcomers giving "deep" answers! FYI the fact that `T` cannot be deduced here is known as **non-deducible context**.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [dependent name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/168175), you need to say:

```
template <typename T>
void func(typename Foo<T>::Bar* bar) // Tell the compiler explicitly it's a type
```

Comment: -1. This answer is incomplete, and doesn't solve the bigger problem in the question.  What you said is true, but how would `func(&foo.bar_)` work? It still would not.