# Overloading operator<<: cannot bind lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’

Tags: c++

I have a class that uses a nested class, and want to use the nested class `operator<<` to define `operator<<` in the upper class. Here is how my code looks like:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct classA {
  struct classB
  {
    template<typename U>
    friend inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out,
                                            const typename classA<U>::classB &b);
  };

  classB root;

  template<typename U>
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out,
                                   const classA<U> &tree);
};

template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out,
                                 const classA<T> &tree)
{
  out << tree.root;
  return out;
}

template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out,
                                 const typename classA<T>::classB &b)
{
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  classA<int> a;
  std::cout << a;
}
```

- When compiling without support for C++11, the definition of operator<< for the inner class seems not to be found by the compiler:

  ```
  so.hpp:24:7: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘out << tree.classA<int>::root’
  so.hpp:24:7: note: candidates are: ...
  ```
- With GCC 4.6 and 4.7 when compiling with std=c++0x:

  ```
  so.hpp:21:3: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
  In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40:0,
                   from so.hpp:2:
  /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:600:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = classA<int>::classB]’
  ```

Can someone tell me why this code is not legal, and what's the best way to do what I want?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Bo provided the *reason* why this is happening (the type `T` is not deducible in the call to the nested `operator<<`. A simple workaround for this, and something that I recommend in general, not only here, is not befriending a template, but rather a single free function. For that you will need to *define* the function inline:

```
template<typename T>
struct classA {
  struct classB
  {
    friend inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out,
                                            const classB &b) {
       // definition goes here
    }
  };

  classB root;

  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out,
                                   const classA<U> &tree) {
       // definition goes here
  }
};
```

There are a couple of differences among the two approaches. The most important one is that this approach will have the compiler define a non-templated overload for `operator<<` for each instantiation of the template, which because it is no longer a template, does not depend on deducing the arguments. Another side effects are that the approach is a little *tighter* (you are only befriending *one* function, while in your initial approach you befriended the template and all possible instantiations (which can be used as a loophole to gain access to your class internals). Finally the functions so defined will only be found through ADL, so there are less overloads of `operator<<` for the compiler to consider when the argument is not `ClassA<T>` or `ClassA<T>::ClassB`.

---

*How access can be gained with your approach*

```
namespace {
   struct intruder {
       ClassA & ref;
       intruder( ClassA& r ) : ref(r) {}
   };
   template <>
   std::ostream& operator<< <intruder>( std::ostream& _, ClassA<intruder> const& i ) {
       std::cout << i.ref.private_member << std::endl;
       return _;
   }
}
```

*Alternative*

Alternatively you can befriend a particular specialization of a template. That will solve the `intruder` problem, as it will only be open to `operator<<` to `ClassA<intruder>`, which has a much lesser impact. But this will not solve your particular issue, as the type would still not be deducible.

Comment: I see it like a *better design* rather than a *workaround*. It has it's downside (you cannot take the address of the friend function declared inside the template class), but on all other accounts it is a better fit to provide free function operators...

Comment: This is the [Making New Friends](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Making_New_Friends) idiom, so not really a workaround.

Comment: @TBBle: It's good that someone found a name for it, but that idiom has been in use for a long time by no name and it is just fine :)

Comment: I wasn't meaning to imply that it stopped being a workaround once it was named. This name for the idiom is at least [10 years old](https://accu.org/index.php/conferences/accu_conference_2007/accu2007_sessions#Making%20New%20Friends). The [changes that made it necessary](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1996/N0968.pdf) are more than 10 years older than that though, as far as I can tell. Although at the time, the examples of this use-case all seemed to go with "pre-declare".

Answer (score 29):

You have a problem with a ["non-deducible context"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6060824/597607) in this operator

```
template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out,
                                 const typename classA<T>::classB &b)
{
  return out;
}
```

The compiler cannot figure out what values of `T` will result in a `classB` that matches the parameter you want to pass. So this template is not considered!

In C++11 mode, the compiler then goes on to find a close match from the standard library

```
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&)
```

where it *can* match `_Tp` to just about any type, including `classA<T>::classB`, but notes that the first parameter doesn't match.

Comment: The comment about the close match made it clear why I was having a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped a lot to understand what are you talking about

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out,
                             const classA<T> &tree)
{
   //out << tree.root;
   ::operator<<( out, tree.root);
   return out;
}
```

and then you will get a straightforward confession of ineptitude:

```
test.cpp:34:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator<<(std::ostream&, const classA<int>::classB&)’
test.cpp:34:3: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:23:22: note: template<class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const     typename classA<T>::classB&)
test.cpp:30:22: note: template<class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const classA<T>&)
```

Workaround: maybe you can use a member function in nested classB, and use it instead of operator<< ... Of course, that solution has a multitude of drawbacks, but it may get you out of this hurry.

Comment: You can always explicitly call `::operator<< <T> (out, tree.root)` instead, but I think that named member functions now look more attractive.