# A way to print of map of multimaps?

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, multimap

I'm trying to overload `operator<<`, and it drove me crazy:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & lhs, TuringMachine::TRTable& rhs){

    for(auto& statePtr : rhs){

        lhs << statePtr.first->getLabel().toStdString();
        for(auto& charPtr: statePtr.second){

            //lhs << '\t';
            lhs << charPtr.first.toAscii() ;
            //lhs << 'b ';
            lhs << charPtr.second.getState().getLabel().toStdString() << std::endl;
        }
    }

return lhs;
}
```

`TRTable` is a `typedef`for  `std::map<State*, std::multimap<QChar, Transition>>`. `State`has  its label as a `QString` hence the call to `.toStdString()`.

In another  class I call `std::cout << machine->table << std::endl;` with `machine` beeing a `TuringMachine*` and this gives me

```
error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
```

What am I doing wrong? Why `&&`?

EDIT: using g++ 4.6 and `-std=c++0x`

Comment: What types do toStdString and toAscii return? Do you know which line the error message is for?

Comment: `toStdString()` and `toAscii()` are member fuctions of `QString` and `QChar`. They return a `std::string` and a `char`, respectively. The error occurs in the line where I call `std::cout << machine->table << std::endl`

Comment: Is a declaration of this `operator<<` function visible from the point where you try to use it?  (Earlier in the same file, or in an #included header)

Comment: It sounds like you changed some things. Let's sync up with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: From the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651161/overlading-operator-cannot-bind-lvalue-to-stdbasic-ostreamchar It sounds similar. The compiler may not be considering your operator for some reason. That makes aschepler's suggestion sound very good!

Comment: @aschepler When putting it in a header, I was getting "multiple  definitions" errors. The I read about making it `inline` and now it works! Thanks you! But why didn't the  guards of the header file suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which namespace did you declare the `operator<<`? Since `TRTable` is a typedef [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) does not apply, so the `operator<<` is searched only in `namespace std` by ADL, since this is where the actual class is defined. So you might have to `use` the namespace where you defined the `operator<<` when you want to use it.

Comment: To my shame I must admit that I simply put it in the .cpp file. I was trying to  avoid the multiple difinitions error  and was plain unaware of the fact that I could do so by leaving it in the header and prefixing it with `inline` and everything's gonna be fine. Just  as it is now :-)

Answer (score 0):

`lhs` should have type `std::ostream &`. No `const`.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted an outdated version of the function. No ` const` present in my actual code.  Updated

Answer (score 0):

`rhs` should be `const TuringMachine::TRTable&`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, const TuringMachine::TRTable& rhs)
```