# how to refactor this class template to minimize boiler-plate code?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, refactoring

I've recently started using [boost mirror](http://kifri.fri.uniza.sk/~chochlik/mirror-lib/html/) for ORM reflection so I can minimize the amount of DB-related boiler-plate code.

One kind of pattern I've run into is listed below.

Since `Bar`'s code is going to look identical even for `Baz`, I was wondering, *is it possible to collapse this code any further?*

It would be nice if the `getValues()` interface would look the same, but the identical implementation could also live in `Foo` instead.

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename T >
struct Foo
{
    static std::ostream& GetValues_Worker( std::ostream& os, T const& t )
    {
        // do boost mirror reflection stuff here
        return os;
    }
};

struct Bar : 
    public Foo<Bar>
{
    // REFACTOR IF POSSIBLE:  this code will always look the same - even for Baz
    std::ostream& 
    getValues( std::ostream& os ) const
    {
        return GetValues_Worker( os, *this );
    }
};

struct Baz : 
    public Foo<Baz>
{
    // REFACTOR IF POSSIBLE:  looks the same as Bar
    std::ostream& 
    getValues( std::ostream& os ) const
    {
        return GetValues_Worker( os, *this );
    }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Bar b;
    std::cerr << b.getValues( std::cerr ) << std::endl;
}
```

**ANSWER**

It turns out that ecatmur's answer below works in most cases.  In my specific situation, I adapted his solution to my real code, it worked in 2 out of 4 cases.  In the two cases where it failed to work, it was a bit beyond the scope of the Mickey-Mouse example that I gave above.  The closest explanation that I could find in SO which explains the compile-time errors I was getting is probably [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347530/error-cannot-bind-stdbasic-ostreamchar-lvalue-to-stdbasic-ostreamchar).  The crux of the problem appeared to be related to what was happening inside my **Worker code**.  In the two failed cases, I was doing output streaming of the subclasses' members based on what I was getting back from runtime reflection results in **boost mirror**.  I think this is turned out to be a case of **non-deducible context**.  I still don't understand why the solution in those two failed cases works exactly (why using a visitor in the form of a virtual method gets around the issue).  Anyhow, I stumbled upon that approach and was trying to reduce the code some more (in those 4 cases), but in two of them, I couldn't really reduce that code any more without running into the **non-deducible context** issue.

Comment: I didn't put a Baz because it would look the same as Bar - I'll add...

Comment: If you have two classes that looks and behaves the same, why have two classes? If they are _mostly_ the same, then you could have a common base class. As you already have a common base class, why not simple make the common functions `virtual` members of the base class?

Comment: `struct Baz : public Foo<Bar>`; should it be `Foo<Baz>`?

Comment: What's the point of having `Bar` and `Baz` then? Just remove one and only use the other.

Comment: @KerrekSB `Bar` and `Baz` are abstractions for different database objects/tables (eg Cat, Dog, Frog tables and objects) - I am using boost mirror to minimize boiler-plate code required to provide functionality to INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE, for instance...

Comment: @iammilind +1 yes - you caught my quick-copy-and-paste-bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bar::getValues` can be moved to `Foo<Bar>` using a CRTP downcast:

```
template< typename T >
struct Foo
{
    static std::ostream& GetValues_Worker( std::ostream& os, T const& t )
    {
        // do boost mirror reflection stuff here
        return os;
    }

    std::ostream& getValues( std::ostream& os ) const
    {
        return GetValues_Worker( os, *static_cast<T const *>(this) );
    }
};
```

At this point you might as well combine the two methods:

```
template< typename T >
struct Foo
{
    std::ostream& getValues( std::ostream& os ) const
    {
        T const &t = *static_cast<T const *>(this);
        // do boost mirror reflection stuff here
        return os;
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 YES!  I think this is what I need - tyvm for the simplified code

Comment: One quick addendum - if that function happened to be `operator==( T const&)` instead, would I be forced to leave it in `Bar` and `Baz` and use the two tier call?

Comment: @kfmfe04 not at all; `Foo<T>` can write `bool operator==(T const &) const` and the correct operator will be picked up by `Bar` and `Baz`.

Comment: After several hours of digging around in SO, I think I'm beginning to understand my special case now.  It has to do with my funky mixing of templates which require compile-time knowledge of types vs my use of reflection, which is necessarily requires dynamic typing.  I will add notes to the OP for future reference.