# error: cannot bind std::ostream lvalue to std::basic_ostream<char>&&

Tags: c++

This has been asked before in [Overloading operator<<: cannot bind lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651161/overloading-operator-cannot-bind-lvalue-to-stdbasic-ostreamchar), the following code results in:

```
error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
```

And the code:

```
// tried forward declaring but this did not help
namespace Tree {
    template<typename> class Node;
};
template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Tree::Node<T>&);

namespace Tree {
    template<typename> class Tree;

    template<typename T>
    class Node {
        friend inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Node& node) {
            return out << node.getData();
        }
        friend class Tree<T>;
        // member declarations
        ...
    };

    template<typename T>
    class Tree {
        friend inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Tree& tree) {
            return tree.showInOrder(out, tree.root);
        }

        std::ostream& showInOrder(std::ostream& out, std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> const &node) const {
            if(node->left) showInOrder(out, node->left);
            out << node << " "; // error: cannot bind 'std:ostream {...} to lvalue'
            if(node->right) showInOrder(out, node->right);
            return out;
        }
    };
};
```

According to Bo Persson's answer in the above link, I have a problem with a ["non-deducible context"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6060824/597607), but the accepted answer there does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Can you give the full error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`node` is a `std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>`. You need to dereference it:

```
out << *node << " ";
```