# Compiler error at line 30 when trying to output vector

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I'm just starting to take C++ courses online and right now, I'm doing vectors. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong on line 30 and 31? I can't seem to output what is in vector_2d at index 0 and 1. Thanks!

```
# include <iostream>
# include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int> vector1 {};
    vector <int> vector2 {};

    vector1.push_back(10);
    vector1.push_back(20);

    cout << vector1.at(0) << endl;
    cout << vector1.at(1) << endl;
    cout << vector1.size() << endl;



    vector2.push_back(100);
    vector2.push_back(200);

    cout << vector2.at(0) << endl;
    cout << vector2.at(1) << endl;

    vector <vector <int>> vector_2d {};

    vector_2d.push_back(vector1);
    vector_2d.push_back(vector2);

    cout << vector_2d.at(0) << endl;
    cout << vector_2d.at(1) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Update, I've copied and pasted below most of the complete error output, I'm limited to 30,000 characters. :

```
C:\Users\FT86TT\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion2021.2\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build "/cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/cmake-build-debug" --target untitled14 -- -j 6
Scanning dependencies of target untitled14
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled14.dir/main.cpp.o
/cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:32:10: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'})
   32 |     cout << vector_2d.at(0) << endl;
      |     ~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |     |                   |
      |     |                   __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type {aka std::vector<int>}
      |     std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:108:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:108:36: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&)' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)'}
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:117:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]'
  117 |       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:117:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type&)' {aka 'std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)'}
  117 |       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:127:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  127 |       operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:127:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)'
  127 |       operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:166:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  166 |       operator<<(long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:166:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'long int'
  166 |       operator<<(long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~^~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:170:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  170 |       operator<<(unsigned long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:170:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'long unsigned int'
  170 |       operator<<(unsigned long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:174:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  174 |       operator<<(bool __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:174:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'bool'
  174 |       operator<<(bool __n)
      |                  ~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:826,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/ostream.tcc:91:5: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
   91 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/ostream.tcc:92:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'short int'
   92 |     operator<<(short __n)
      |                ~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:181:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  181 |       operator<<(unsigned short __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:181:33: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'short unsigned int'
  181 |       operator<<(unsigned short __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:826,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/ostream.tcc:105:5: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'
  105 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/ostream.tcc:106:20: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'int'
  106 |     operator<<(int __n)
      |                ~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:192:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  192 |       operator<<(unsigned int __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:192:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'unsigned int'
  192 |       operator<<(unsigned int __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:201:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  201 |       operator<<(long long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:201:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'long long int'
  201 |       operator<<(long long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:205:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  205 |       operator<<(unsigned long long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:205:37: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'long long unsigned int'
  205 |       operator<<(unsigned long long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:220:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  220 |       operator<<(double __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:220:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'double'
  220 |       operator<<(double __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:224:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  224 |       operator<<(float __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:224:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'float'
  224 |       operator<<(float __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~^~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:232:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  232 |       operator<<(long double __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:232:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'long double'
  232 |       operator<<(long double __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:245:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
  245 |       operator<<(const void* __p)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:245:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'const void*'
  245 |       operator<<(const void* __p)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:826,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/ostream.tcc:119:5: note: candidate: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]'
  119 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/ostream.tcc:120:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} to 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__streambuf_type*' {aka 'std::basic_streambuf<char>*'}
  120 |     operator<<(__streambuf_type* __sbin)
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/string:55,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:6530:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)'
 6530 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:6530:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:32:27: note:   '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'} is not derived from 'const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
   32 |     cout << vector_2d.at(0) << endl;
      |                           ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:46,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/system_error:263:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::error_code&)'
  263 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, const error_code& __e)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/system_error:263:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:32:25: note:   cannot convert 'vector_2d.std::vector<std::vector<int> >::at(0)' (type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int> >, std::vector<int> >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector<int>'}) to type 'const std::error_code&'
   32 |     cout << vector_2d.at(0) << endl;
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:506:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT)'
  506 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, _CharT __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:506:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/cygdrive/c/Users/FT86TT/Desktop/COP 3363/untitled14/main.cpp:32:27: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_CharT' ('char' and 'std::vector<int>')
   32 |     cout << vector_2d.at(0) << endl;
      |                           ^
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a comment on the line you get the error, And please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question.

Comment: As a (probable) hint: What type of object will e.g. `vector_2d.at(0)` return? And is there a stream output operator `<<` overload for that type?

Comment: The compiler error, while probably looking like gibberish to you, actually contains a precise description of the problem.  It's a good idea to practice reading error messages.  And if you are writing a question about an error message, it's best to include the entire message for those of us who do read it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609915/stdvector-cannot-bind-stdostream-aka-stdbasic-ostreamchar-lvalue-t

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the vector `vector_2d` are in turn objects of the type `std::vector<int>`.

```
vector <vector <int>> vector_2d {};
```

There is no standard overloaded `operator <<` for vectors. So the compiler issues error messages for these statements

```
cout << vector_2d.at(0) << endl;
cout << vector_2d.at(1) << endl;
```

You could use the range based for loop to output elements of the vectors as for example

```
for ( const auto &item : vector_2d.at(0) )
{
    std::cout << item << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';

for ( const auto &item : vector_2d.at(1) )
{
    std::cout << item << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Otherwise you need to overload the `operator <<` for the class `std::vector<int>` yourself as for example

```
$include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream &os, const std::vector<int> &v )
{
    for (const auto &item : v)
    {
        os << item << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    std::cout << v << '\n';
}
```

And call the operator like

```
std::cout << vector_2d.at(0) << '\n';
```

Pay attention to that this initialization of the vectors

```
vector <int> vector1 {};
vector <int> vector2 {};
```

is redundant and has no effect. You could just write

```
vector <int> vector1;
vector <int> vector2;
```

In the both cases empty vectors are defined.

Bear in mind that for your program there is no great sense to use the member function `at`. You could use the subscript operator like

```
vector_2d[0]
```

Otherwise when you are using the member function `at` when it is better to enclose it in a try-catch block.

Answer (score -1):

`vector_2d` is of type `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, so `vector_2d.at(0)` and `vector_2d.at(1)` is of type `std::vector`. Since `std::cout` don't know how to print an object of type `std::vector<int>`, it gives an error.

If you want to print the whole vector, do:

```
for(const auto &i : vector_2d.at(0))
{
    std::cout << i << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n'
for(const auto &i : vector_2d.at(1))
{
    std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed:

```
cout << vector_2d.at(0) << endl;
cout << vector_2d.at(1) << endl;
```

to:

```
cout << vector_2d.at(0).at(0) << " " << vector_2d.at(0).at(1) << endl;
cout << vector_2d.at(1).at(0) << " " << vector_2d.at(1).at(1) << endl;
```

Thanks all!