# Implicit template deduction with lambda expressions

Tags: templates, c++11, lambda

I have the following code I try to build with c++11 on XCode 5.1:

```
template<class T>
float calc2(std::function<float(T)> f) { return -1.0f * f(3.3f) + 666.0f; }

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    calc2([](float arg) -> float{ return arg * 0.5f; }); //(1) - Will not compile - no matching function...
    calc2<float>([](float arg) -> float{ return arg * 0.5f; }); // (2) - Compiles well
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain why (1) does not compile? Shouldn't the compiler deduce T from the lambda definition?

Thanks!

Comment: `std::function` may be a misnomer, it is a function wrapper. Lambda expressions have unique types unrelated to `std::function`, therefore, template type deduction cannot succeed.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14784441/420683

Comment: You can only deduce from things you pass in directly, not from things that might be convertible to other things. E.g. try `calc2(std::function<float(float)>([](float arg){return arg/2;}))`.

Comment: So what is the correct way if I want to enforce the input/output parameters of the function/lambda that calc2 receives?

Comment: That would be something like a concept. Unfortunately, that cannot be done easily in C++11. You can, for example, try `template<class F, class = typename std::enable_if< std::is_convertible<typename std::result_of<F(float)>::type, float>{} >::type> float calc2(F f);`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes nothing is the right thing to do. C++ type system will do the dirty work for you:

```
template<class F>
float calc2(F f)
{
  return -1.0f * f(3.3f) + 666.0f;
}
```

If you pass it anything that would make the function invalid, it will naturally fail to compile.

The downside is that if you pass it anything that would *not* make the function invalid, it will compile, even if it makes no sense. If you want to be more selective, you can use `static_assert`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class F>
float calc2(F f)
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<float, decltype(f(std::declval<float>()))>::value,
                "The argument must return float when called with float arg!");

  return -1.0f * f(3.3f) + 666.0f;
}
```

Comment: Arguably, this is a bit greedy. E.g. you can get problems with overload resolution for `calc2`.

Comment: @dyp well, your method in the comment does have the exact same problem. One needs to add an overload like `float calc2(float (*f)(float))` to fix it.

Comment: @dyp not much more than a `std::function`, whose greedyness knows few bounds.