# Define std::hash for enum member of class template

Tags: c++, hash, enums, c++14

Let’s say we have the following class:

```
template <int i>
class S {
public:
    enum class E : signed char {a, b, c};
    // ...
};
```

And now I want to have a hash function for E. The following works:

```
namespace std {
template<>
struct hash<typename S<3>::E> {
    size_t operator()(typename S<3>::E const& e) const { return 0; }
};
}
```

But if I make it generic it does not:

```
namespace std {
template<int i>
struct hash<typename S<i>::E> {
    size_t operator()(typename S<i>::E const& e) const { return 0; }
};
}
// error C2764: 'i': template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization 'std::hash<S<i>::E>'
```

How can I make sure to always be able to hash S::E for all i?

Comment: What if all `S<i>` had `E` be a typedef of some other single type? `i` can't be figured out in the general sense. It isn't quite the same, but there are some similar answers on here. Found one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060824/c-template-argument-can-not-be-deduced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typename S<3>::E` denotes a particular type. It is fine to declare an explicit specialization of `std::hash` for that type. If that type is ever used as a template argument to `std::hash`, then your explicit specialization will be used.

On the other hand, there is no way that your partial specialization

```
template<int i>
struct hash<typename S<i>::E>
```

can ever be used. As the error says, `i` is not deducible. For any given `T`, the compiler cannot determine whether `std::hash<T>` should use your partial specialization because it has no way of telling whether there exists an `i` such that `typename S<i>::E` is the same type as `T`. If `i` were used in a deduced context, such as:

```
template<int i>
struct hash<S<i>>
```

it would be different, because then the compiler could simply attempt to deduce `i`. The compiler can know *for sure* whether a given type is `S<i>` where `S` is a template known to it.  If `T` is `S<i>` for some `i`, then the deduction succeeds, otherwise it fails and the specialization is ignored. In a non-deduced context, the compiler can't tell.

How to fix? If `E` were a class type, I would suggest making it a template that would not be nested inside `S`. Then you could specialize `std::hash` for `E<i>`. However, you can't have enum templates, so that's out. You could perhaps just have a single non-template enum and a hash specialization for that type, then have `S<i>::E` be a typedef to that enum for all `i`. If you don't want users to rely on the fact that `S<i>::E` is the same type for all `i`, you can just say that the definition of `S<i>::E` is unspecified.

Comment: Right. So how do I make sure that I can always hash S<i>::E for all i?

Comment: OK, thanks. I accept the fact that doing exactly what I want is not possible.

Comment: I believe you can also define `E` in some scary-looking `namespace` (like the infamous `detail`) and then put `using E = detail::E;` into `S`. You can specialize `std::hash<detail::E>` but your users need not know that.

Comment: @5gon12eder yes, that's the idea