# C++ Why does error "no matching function" appear when it 100% looks like they match?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, c++11, generic-programming

I don't understand why I'm getting an error that states my function doesn't match my defined template function. To me, they look **exactly** the same. Here is the error in my debug:

`error: no matching function for call to 'mergesort' newVec = mergesort(vec.begin(),vec.end());`

So I can learn and write better generic functions and templates, what do I need to change to make that error go away? (Just to be clear, I'm not asking for help with my mergesort algorithm - I know it has problems, but I'll work them out.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
vector<T> mergesort(typename vector<T>::iterator, typename vector<T>::iterator);

int main() {
    vector<int> vec{ 50, 5, 40, 10, 30, 15, 20, 20, 10, 25 };
    vector<int> newVec;

    newVec = mergesort(vec.begin(),vec.end()); //Doesn't match???

    cout << "before:";
    for (auto x : vec) cout << x << ' '; cout << '\n';
    cout << "after :";
    for (auto x : newVec) cout << x << ' '; cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
vector<T> mergesort(typename vector<T>::iterator begin, typename vector<T>::iterator end){
    vector<T> newVector;
    copy(begin, end, newVector);

    if(begin!=end){
        vector<T> tmp1;
        vector<T> tmp2;

        auto dist = distance(newVector.begin(),newVector.end());
        auto distance1 = dist/2;
        auto distance2 = (dist/2+1);

        auto mid1 = newVector.begin();
        auto mid2 = newVector.begin();

        advance(mid1,distance1);
        advance(mid2,distance2);

        tmp1 = mergesort(newVector.begin(), mid1);
        tmp2 = mergesort(mid2, newVector.end());

        merge(tmp1.begin(), mid1, mid2, tmp2.end(), newVector.begin());

        return newVector;
    } else {
        return newVector;
    }
}
```

Comment: The term to search for is *non-deduced context*.

Comment: @T.C.  Ok, I'll look that up.

Comment: @T.C. - that phase has been really useful, and now I understand that my compiler isn't able to deduce it. But I've tried what is shown in several examples, especially this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context ... I still just can't wrap my head around this - I'm sure it's a simple concept, but I just don't get what I did wrong.

Comment: Why are you using `typename vector<T>::iterator` rather than `vector<T>::iterator`?

Comment: Because my compiler said I required it in debug, and a huge amount of error messages went away when I did. I know that's not a good answer, but that's why.

Comment: @c650 [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/2069064)

Comment: @Barry I know about `template`, but I've gotten _this_ far without using `typename` as it is used above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that this is a non-deduced context:

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> mergesort(typename vector<T>::iterator, typename vector<T>::iterator);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There are [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6060877/2069064) [good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245676/2069064) answers for why this function call fails to compile.

As to how to fix it - even if the above code did work, there's no reason to limit your functionality to `vector` iterators anyway. You can merge-sort other containers too. So just deduce any iterator:

```
template <typename Iterator>
vector<T> mergesort(Iterator, Iterator);
```

Moreover, typically we'd typically expect the merge to be modifying the range provided, not returning a new container. So really prefer:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void mergesort(Iterator, Iterator);
```

---

There's a few other issues in your code. The call to `std::merge()` here:

```
merge(tmp1.begin(), mid1, mid2, tmp2.end(), newVector.begin());
```

`newVector` is empty before this call, so we're just going to overwrite memory that it doesn't own. You'll want to do:

```
newVector.reserve(dist);
merge(tmp1.begin(), mid1, mid2, tmp2.end(), std::back_inserter(newVector));
```

Comment: Good answer, that got me to the right direction - thanks!