# Why does the vector iterator point out of bounds?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, recursion, mergesort

I'm studying a recursive mergesort algorithm, and one iterator goes out of bounds. I'm positive the root of my problem is that my algorithm is flawed, but I've spent days pouring over it, and I just don't see my misstep. I don't know what direction to take. Can someone more experienced/smarter than I take a look? (Full program with driver is available on Github [here](https://github.com/NonCreature0714/Recursion_example_with_mergesort/blob/master/main.cpp).)

Output is:

```
before: 50 5 40 10 30 15 20 20 10 25 
after : -1808873259 5 10 10 15 20 20 25 30 40 50 
/*      ^  
 *      Extra recursive call, and out-of-bounds.
 */
```

To be clear, I am constrained to returning a vector of type T, in this case int, but I'm aware from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105971/c-why-does-error-no-matching-function-appear-when-it-100-looks-like-they-ma) that using a void function is better.

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> mergesort(typename vector<T>::iterator begin, typename vector<T>::iterator end){
    vector<T> newVector;
    if (begin!=end){
        vector<T> tmp1;
        vector<T> tmp2;
        typename vector<T>::iterator mid1 = begin;
        typename vector<T>::iterator mid2 = begin;

        long origDistance = distance(begin,end);
        long endOfRange1 = origDistance/2;
        long begOfRange2 = endOfRange1+1;

        advance(mid1,endOfRange1);
        advance(mid2,begOfRange2);

        tmp1 = mergesort<T>(begin,mid1);
        tmp2 = mergesort<T>(mid2,end);

        //"merge()" is from the STL, link in comments. 
        merge(tmp1.begin(),tmp1.end(),tmp2.begin(),tmp2.end(), back_inserter(newVector));

    } else {
        newVector.push_back(*begin);
    }
    return newVector;
}
```

Comment: Updating soon with output for example.

Comment: Are you aware that `some_vector.end()` is not the last element, but one past the last? It's illegal to dereference that. I don't know what the `merge` function does, but that could be the reason.

Comment: The best way to understand why your program behaves the way it does is to run it under a debugger.  In the end, you'll learn much more by doing this than you will by asking us to help you figure things out.  Good luck!

Comment: Also show how you call this function

Comment: Merge is from the STL here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/?kw=merge

Comment: I'll mark correct answer tomorrow - it's midnight were I am and I've been looking at this for 8 hours already. (In code's previous iterations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dereference `begin` when `begin == end`.  That's undefined behavior.  Probably you want `if (origDistance == 1)` then push_back the single element and return.

Comment: ...assuming that `end` is an end iterator (which we can't tell based on what is posted)

Comment: @M.M: If `end` is not an end iterator then I give up.  =)

Comment: Still working this out - but this got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks like it could work, if `end` points to the last element of the vector. However in your sample program you call it like this:

> ```
> newVector = mergesort<int>(vec.begin(), vec.end());
> ```

The `vec.end()` points past the end of the vector, it doesn't point to the last element. So your function messes up because it ultimately tries to access the element pointed to by the second iterator you pass in.

You *could* call your function like: `mergesort<int>(vec.begin(), vec.end() - 1);`.

However this will surprise anyone else reading your code. It would be much better to rewrite your `mergesort` function to follow normal C++ range conventions, that is, the parameter named `end` should be past-the-end.  `mid1` should equal `mid2`.

Comment: Thanks, this also is helping get me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't mark you both correct - you were a huge help @M.M

Answer (score 0):

Okay - couldn't go to sleep without figuring this out, and huge credit goes to [John Zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4323/john-zwinck) and [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) for getting me in the right direction - here's the code which got the correct output:

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> mergesort(typename vector<T>::iterator begin, typename vector<T>::iterator end){
    vector<T> newVector;
    long origDistance = distance(begin,end); /*Get distance first.*/

    if (origDistance==1){ /*Added better anchor case checking for distance.*/
        newVector.push_back(*begin);
        return newVector;
    }

    vector<T> tmp1;
    vector<T> tmp2;
    typename vector<T>::iterator mid1 = begin;
    typename vector<T>::iterator mid2 = begin;

    long endOfRange1 = origDistance/2;
    long begOfRange2 = endOfRange1;/*Edited from: endOfRange+1*/

    advance(mid1,endOfRange1);
    advance(mid2,begOfRange2);

    tmp1 = mergesort<T>(begin,mid1);
    tmp2 = mergesort<T>(mid2,end);

    merge(tmp1.begin(),tmp1.end(),tmp2.begin(),tmp2.end(), back_inserter(newVector));
        return newVector;
}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to also allow for `begin == end` (i.e. the empty vector as input)

Answer (score -3):

Here I will show you how to do it.

```
template <typename T>
void mergesort(typename vector<T>::iterator, typename vector<T>::iterator);

// ...

    mergesort<int>(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    newVector = vec;

// ...

template <typename T>
void mergesort(typename vector<T>::iterator begin, typename vector<T>::iterator end){
    auto const N = std::distance(begin, end);
    if (N <= 1) return;                   
    auto const middle = std::next(begin, N / 2);
    mergesort<T>(begin, middle);
    mergesort<T>(middle, end);
    std::inplace_merge(begin, middle, end); 
}
```

Correct output:

```
before: 50 5 40 10 30 15 20 20 10 25 
after : 5 10 10 15 20 20 25 30 40 50
```

STL already has inplace_merge so why reimplement it? With this approach you don't have to think has hard with boundaries.

Comment: You begin your answer with "You are just like a little baby."  Nice one.

Comment: Hi @SalmanPatel, I'm sure you didn't intend to insult the OP.  Just rewrite your first sentence.

Comment: Yes, indeed, StackOverflow is my favorite place to hide answers.

Comment: Until your answer accounts for having to return vector<T>, my specific constraint, it is incorrect.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer. OP asked where the mistake is in his code. You have not answered that question.