# Is there a way to match a nested template type implicitly in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    int n = 42;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<A> Ptr;
};

template<typename T>
void foo(typename T::Ptr arg) {
    std::cout << arg->n << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void bar(T arg) {
    std::cout << arg.n << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    A::Ptr a = A::Ptr(new A());
    foo<A>(a); // Can I avoid giving <A> here explicitly.
    // foo(a); // does not compile
    bar(*a); // after all this does work
    return 0;
}
```

To me it looks like it should also be possible to call `foo(a)` instead of `foo<A>(a)`. Why is this not possible and can I somehow change the definition of `foo` to make this possible?

I realize that I could just skip the `::Ptr` in the signature, but I still want to have access to the `A` type without the pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not possible *because* that is non-deducible context.

The type of `a` is just `std::shared_ptr<A>`, which means **if** `foo(a)` works, **then** the following should *also* work:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> x(new A());
foo(x);
```

If so, then what should `T` be deduced to — and why? You might be tempted to say "*`T` should be deduced to `A`, because `A` has a nested type `Ptr` which is same as `std::shared_ptr<A>`*". Well, what if there is another class defined as:

```
struct B
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr<A> Ptr;
};
```

What should `T` be deduced to? `A` or `B`? or something else?

Here is another topic that discusses *non-deducible context* using a different example:

- [C++, template argument can not be deduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060824/c-template-argument-can-not-be-deduced)

Hope that helps.

Comment: what is a "non-deducible context"? how does it work? where does it apply?

Comment: @Ven In a nutshell, it applies whenever the compiler has no sane way to deduce the parameter which remains sane in the presence of corner cases and an unbounded set of types and values. For a more formal treatment, refer to chapter 14 of the C++ standard.

Comment: @Angew I just wanted a more complete answer than the one-line.

Answer (score 4):

Nawaz's answer has explained why the code doesn't work, I'll focus on this question:

> but I still want to have access to the `A` type without the pointer.

[`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) has a member type `element_type`, you could use it like `typename T::element_type`. And if you want the code works well with raw pointer too, you could provide a trait class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct trait_element_type {
    using element_type = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct trait_element_type<std::shared_ptr<T>> {
    using element_type = T;
};
```

And then use it as:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T arg) {

    std::cout << arg->n << std::endl;

    typename trait_element_type<T>::element_type x; // retrieve the element type
    std::cout << x.n << std::endl;
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/BAMF11821)

Comment: In the specialization, it could be just `using element_type = T;` instead of `using element_type = typename std::shared_ptr<T>::element_type;`.